# Preserve comments for mapped types in d.ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, typescript-declarations, typescript-language-server

In the latest Typescript (v5.0.4 as for today) when I compile declarations for the following code:

```js
type SomeType<T> = {
  field: T;
};

const getInstance = <T>(
  value: T
): SomeType<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}> => {
  return {
    field: value,
  };
};

export const variable = getInstance({
  /**
   * want to have it in d.ts
   */
  nested: "nested",
});
```

I'm getting this in my `d.ts`:

```js
type SomeType<T> = {
    field: T;
};
export declare const variable: SomeType<{
    nested: string;
}>;
export {};
```

Which reflects what we have in the code, but unfortunately there is no comment. I happens specifically when I use mapped types in the returned type.

It would have been work fine If I don't use mapped type, but unfortunately I can't get rid of it in my case.

The question is how to preserve the comment in the d.ts file with mapped type? Nice stuff is that I see my comment in VSCode when I hover over `variable.field.nested` property which means that Typescript preserves it somewhere but just doesn't add it to d.ts file on declaration generation stage.

Comment: ① Also note that the `k` in `{[k in keyof T]: T[k]}` is a generic type parameter and not an identifier name, so it is conventionally written in UpperPascalCase like `K` instead. ② I don't really understand all the rules for how comments are preserved/omitted in declaration files, but... couldn't you just create a new named type and use it as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxkvGN)? If that works for you, I could write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @jcalz, it's not very obvious but it solved the problem, thank you. My original use case is intended to generate much more complicated types but it seems to be working, I'm seeing comments in d.ts with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find authoritative documentation for exactly how the compiler chooses to preserve or discard comments in declaration files, but since you said it works fine if you just wrote `SomeType<T>` instead of `SomeType<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}>`, that suggests comments might be preserved when using a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) directly like `XXX<T>`. So what if we defined an `XXX` that behaves how you want?

```
// .ts file
type GetInstance<T> =
    SomeType<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] }>;

const getInstance = <T,>(value: T
): GetInstance<T> => {
    return {
        field: value,
    };
};

export const variable = getInstance({
    /**
     * want to have it in d.ts
     */
    nested: "nested",
});
```

This is equivalent to your code.  And when we check the generated declaration file, the comment is indeed preserved!

```
// .d.ts file
export declare const variable: GetInstance<{
    /**
     * want to have it in d.ts
     */
    nested: string;
}>;
export {};
```

If anyone finds where such behavior is documented I'd be happy to add it here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwFgAoKcqAMwEsIAbAEwC4pkBuUgXw5NNEigBxCMACSAOwDOwAIbiAxhmx5SFWIhRp0BKAG0A0lGrioAawgg4lVgF0WyAzaicsPUvLhTgUAOYiJ0nKKeFCYADRYABQAbjJ0AK4Q9qQAlCzCYl5BSji4OMRkFABOIvFFJgVqajT0zFCxCRBhqhTcXG4kEAAeYHBF3h5e9TJF1DIARnTQ+H6ZgQoQkZUUAPQAVGstFGtQAO5y3sBwUAAWMtHQ1N7GUAwAdMCSW+RrK8-iENIQdQBEH18MH7NEicFI8IA)